# How to get Side by Side textviews with one that wraps

Tags: android, textview, word-wrap

I have a `listview` with a custom adapter in which I have 3 `textview`s, two are next to each other and one is below the others.  The problem I am running into though, is when the first `textview` extends, it pushes the other `textview` off the screen.

I have not been able to successfully get this to work, here is an example of what's happening:

[image]

As you can see when the first `textview` gets too long, it then pushes the other text off the screen.  I would like it so it wraps but the date `textview` is also showing.  It should also be functional in horizontal view.

Here's the `listview` adapter code:

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/vw1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


<TextView android:id="@+id/liName" android:textSize="17sp"
    android:textColor="#333" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="left"
    android:layout_gravity="left" />
<TextView android:id="@+id/liDate" android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textColor="#666" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="right"
    android:layout_gravity="right" android:width="60sp" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/liName" />

<TextView android:id="@+id/liNum" android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textColor="#666" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/liName" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming that the text view being pushed is the liDate one.
You need to put this one before the liName in your layout and set the width to "wrap_content" and align it right. Then you lace the liName to the left of it with "fill_parent" width
So it would look like this:

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/vw1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


<TextView android:id="@+id/liDate" android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textColor="#666" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:width="60sp" 
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
<TextView android:id="@+id/liName" android:textSize="17sp"
    android:textColor="#333" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/liDate" />

<TextView android:id="@+id/liNum" android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textColor="#666" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/liName" />
```

Hope this is what you meant

Comment: Don't need to re-order code if u use "@+id" in layout_toLeftOf. :>

Comment: Are you sure about this? I don't think the liName view can be created on the left or a view that doesn't exist yet. I think I ran into that problem before and that's why I made it a habit to define them in that order. But I could be wrong

Answer (score 0):

The key was using "@+id/" for the first textview instead of "@id/"
This worked for me:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listEventTypeText"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/listEventDateText"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listEventDateText"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/listEventTypeText"
        />
    </RelativeLayout>
```